# How make go import packages from vendor?

Tags: go, glide-golang

I was checking the vendor feature in go with glide. It was awesome installing all packages but I couldn't manage to make go command to found them in the vendor packages.

```
go run src/main.go

src/main.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/valyala/fasthttp" in any of:
   /home/joaonrb/.software/lib/go/go1.7/src/github.com/valyala/fasthttp (from $GOROOT)
   /home/joaonrb/.projects/go-blog/src/github.com/valyala/fasthttp (from $GOPATH)
```

Fasthttp is installed in `/home/joaonrb/.projects/go-blog/src/vendor/github.com/valyala/fasthttp`, the version of go I'm using is 1.7 and my GOPATH is `/home/joaonrb/.projects/go-blog`

Comment: You shouldn't ever have source files in the top level of "$GOPATH/src". Move your `main.go` into a package directory, and try `go run` from in there.

Comment: Thank you. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your GOPATH structure does not seem valid. To do what you want:

- Create a "project" folder, e.g. `$GOPATH/src/myproj`.
- Put your main.go there.
- Create a vendor folder there, e.g. `$GOPATH/src/myproj/vendor`.
- Put `github.com/valyala/fasthttp` there.

That should work.

Comment: Did this and the error is pretty much the same. It try to find $GOPATH/src/github.com/valyala/fasthttp but the package is in $GOPATH/go-blog/vendor/github.com/valyala/fasthttp

Comment: @joaonrb It should be $GOPATH/**src**/go-blog/vendor/github.com/valyala/fasthttp See my edit.